# Arduino + HC-05 + AndroidVR App (using Unity google cardboard)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arduino

I have been trying this for a week now ...I just not getting what's going on.
So here what I'm trying to achieve.

**I want to send my MPU_6050 data to AndroidVR app via classic HC-05 Bluetooth module.so that I can rotate the cube.**

First of all ,all by connection are good well connected and working coz I have used in Terminal App.

I have performed the same thing using Serial Port with Desktop it work like charm...I just need to print the data in series as

```
1.01,22.1,35.1,
```

using Serial.print();

and on unity side I can get the value in string Array and can split() function something like this

```
string[] output_array = sp.ReadLine().Split(',');
```

here is sp is serial class object . but I cant used Serial port in Android .Can I?

so I'm using this Bluetooth plugin :
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/android-microcontrollers-bluetooth-16467

Now the problem I'm facing is first in Arduino ... as i'm using

> Serial.write();

- so I won't get the accurate result eg: 0.36 would be 0
- second if the value is -14.3 i.e., negative so it would be 255-14 it wold send 241

Now in the Unity I don't know how do I split the data ... and get the value from the list . converting it to string in Unity would give ASCII value which I don't want.

Below is the simple code...please help me with this .

### Arduino code :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define SEPARATOR 255
void setup()
{      
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();

  calibrate_sensors();  
  set_last_read_angle_data(millis(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
 void loop()
{ 
  /* Every thing above work well and all calculation are Performed
  I'm using Complimentary Filter for MPU6050 */

  byte buf[]={angle_x ,angle_y, angle_z,SEPARATOR}; 
  //here first three values are x,y,z angle and a separator(255 as per ASCII) 

  Serial.write(buf,sizeof(buf));//sending the data(byte array) via HC-05. 
}
```

### Unity C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TechTweaking.Bluetooth;

public class JoystickHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    public Text statusText;
    public Text logsOnScreen;

    public Transform cube;


    public float speed = 1.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        statusText.text = "Status : ...";

        BluetoothAdapter.enableBluetooth();
        device = new BluetoothDevice();
        device.Name = "HC-05";
        //device.MacAddress = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX";

        device.setEndByte(255);

        device.ReadingCoroutine = ManageConnection;


    }

    public void connect()
    {
        device.connect();
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        device.close();
    }

    IEnumerator ManageConnection(BluetoothDevice device)
    {
        statusText.text = "Status : Connected & Can read";
        while (device.IsConnected && device.IsReading)
        {
            byte[] packets = device.read();

            if (packets != null)
            {
                statusText.text = "so we got some data";
                int val1 = packets[0];
                int val2 = packets[1];
                int val3 = packets[2];

                logsOnScreen.text = val1+" , "+val2+","+val3;

                cube.Rotate(val1,val2,val3);
            }
            yield return null;
        }
        statusText.text = "Status : Done Reading";

    }
}
```

I know I know its not the prettiest code ...but just trying to achieve the goal and I know I should have used Vector3 and other but this is just for testing purpose ...so kept simple .Please let me know your thought.

Answer (score 0):

*Way too late but the answer may be useful for strangers wandering by*

The problem is that you're taking 3 floating point values and converting them into bytes to send them across the bluetooth serial stream. When you do this conversion you are getting signed 8-bit integers, which is why the decimal values are dropped and why negative values wrap around to high byte values (the sign bit in action).

There are 3 ways to fix this problem

- Use Serial.print(...) to send the numbers as text, this is less efficient and forces you to do a parse at the other end, it is however pretty simple and works fine for small applications
- Multiply the values by 100 to elminiate the decimal points, then divide them by the same value at the other end. In this case an 8-bit integer will not suffice so you will need to use 16-bit ints, which again involves some annoying conversions.
- Take the 4 bytes making up your floating point numbers and send those across. On the Arduino end you can use something like [C Function to Convert float to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420246/c-function-to-convert-float-to-byte-array) On the c# you can very easily convert them back using BitConverter.